# How to sort data in the dictionary of list of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Please help me. I have dataset like this:

```
 my_dict = { 'project_1' : [{'commit_number':'14','name':'john'},
                            {'commit_number':'10','name':'steve'}],
             'project_2' : [{'commit_number':'12','name':'jack'},
                            {'commit_number':'15','name':'anna'},
                            {'commit_number':'11','name':'andy'}]
           }
```

I need to sort the dataset based on the commit number in descending order and make it into a new list by ignoring the name of the project using python. The list expected will be like this:

```
ordered_list_of_dict = [{'commit_number':'15','name':'anna'},
                        {'commit_number':'14','name':'john'},
                        {'commit_number':'12','name':'jack'},
                        {'commit_number':'11','name':'andy'},
                        {'commit_number':'10','name':'steve'}]
```

Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Extract `my_dict`'s values as a list of lists*
2. Join each sub-list together (flatten `dict_values`) to form a flat list
3. Sort each element by `commit_number`

<sub>*list of lists on python2. On python3, a `dict_values` object is returned.</sub>

```
from itertools import chain

res = sorted(chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()), 
             key=lambda x: x['commit_number'], 
             reverse=True)

[{'commit_number': '15', 'name': 'anna'},
 {'commit_number': '14', 'name': 'john'},
 {'commit_number': '12', 'name': 'jack'},
 {'commit_number': '11', 'name': 'andy'},
 {'commit_number': '10', 'name': 'steve'}]
```

On python2, you'd use `dict.itervalues` instead of `dict.values` to the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Coldspeed's answer is great as usual but as an alternative, you can use the following:

```
ordered_list_of_dict = sorted([x for y in my_dict.values() for x in y], key=lambda x: x['commit_number'], reverse=True)
```

which, when printed, gives:

```
print(ordered_list_of_dict)
# [{'commit_number': '15', 'name': 'anna'}, {'commit_number': '14', 'name': 'john'}, {'commit_number': '12', 'name': 'jack'}, {'commit_number': '11', 'name': 'andy'}, {'commit_number': '10', 'name': 'steve'}]
```

Note that in the `list-comprehension` you have the standard construct for flattening a *list of lists*:

`[x for sublist in big_list for x in sublist]`

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide the less-pythonic and more reader-friendly answer.

First, iterate through key-value pairs in my_dict, and add each element of value to an empty list. This way you avoid having to flatten out a list of lists:

```
commits = []
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    for commit in val:
        commits.append(commit)
```

which gives this:

```
In [121]: commits
Out[121]: 
[{'commit_number': '12', 'name': 'jack'},
 {'commit_number': '15', 'name': 'anna'},
 {'commit_number': '11', 'name': 'andy'},
 {'commit_number': '14', 'name': 'john'},
 {'commit_number': '10', 'name': 'steve'}]
```

Then sort it in descending order:

```
sorted(commits, reverse = True)
```

This will sort based on 'commit_number' even if you don't specify it because it comes alphabetically before 'name'. If you want to specify it for the sake of [defensive coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), this would be fastest and cleanest way, to the best of my knowledge :

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(commits, key = itemgetter('commit_number'), reverse = True)
```